# Can I ignore comment lines while reading in a csv file in Octave/MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parsing, csv, comments, octave

I've got a data file that looks like:

```
# data file
# blah
# blah

       0.000000, 0.0, 24.198, 6.864,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
       0.020000, 0.0, 24.198, 6.864,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
       0.040000, 0.0, 24.198, 6.864,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
       0.060000, 0.0, 24.198, 6.864,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
       0.080000, 0.0, 24.198, 6.864,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
       0.100000, 0.0, 24.198, 6.864,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
       0.120000, 0.0, 24.198, 6.864,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

and I'd like to read it with an Octave program.

csvread(file,3,0) works perfectly in this case, but I worry about having to work out the 3 by hand.

Is there some way to say 'throw away any lines starting with #, and any blank lines, before doing the csvread'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In octave you could do

```
d = load("yourfile")
```

which should ignore the # lines

**Edit:**
The above uses autodetection of the file type, you could also force it with `d = load ("-ascii", "yourfile").` Quote from `help load`:

```
 '-ascii'
      Force Octave to assume the file contains columns of numbers in
      text format without any header or other information.  Data in
      the file will be loaded as a single numeric matrix with the
      name of the variable derived from the name of the file.
```

Unfortunately the help doesn't mention that lines starting with % or # are ignored. For this you have to look at the source code (which is fortunately available since GNU Octave is free software) [get_mat_data_input_line from octave source](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/4122df73e374/libinterp/corefcn/ls-mat-ascii.cc#l69)

From there you can see that all chars after % or # are skipped.

Comment: Beautifully simple, and fast, thanks ! Wish I had seen your answer before writing mine...

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html, seems it defaults to "-ascii"

Comment: @huntj: The load command doesn't have a default but it tries to autodetect the file type. The default for save is "-text" which is also human readable but includes the var type, size and other infos.

Answer (score 3):

`csvread` does not allow this option. Instead, you can use `textscan`, but then, you need to know how many columns (or rows) your csv file has.

For example:

```
fid = fopen('csvFile.csv','r');
c = textscan(fid,'%f','commentStyle','#','delimiter',',');
fclose(fid); %# close the file as soon as we don't need it anymore

array = reshape([c{:}],[],7)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to skip header lines starting with a comment string. The `csvread` line could be replaced by a `dlmread` call for delimiters other than `','`. Both these functions are much faster than `textscan` on octave 3.8.2.

```
fid = fopen('csvFile.csv','r');

comment = '#';
while strcmp(fgets(fid, length(comment)), comment)
    % line begins with a comment, skip it
    fskipl(fid);
endwhile
% get back, because the last read length(comment) characters
% are not comments, actually
fseek(fid, -length(comment), SEEK_CUR);

c = csvread(fid);

fclose(fid);
```